# Android Leaderboards Actionbar Icon

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I'm developing a mobile game and I came across a strange problem. I'm using GameHelper class in my project. When I start Leaderboards Activity there is a standard Android icon in ActionBar instead of my icon. I have my icon in mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi and I even tried to put it to drawable folder without specifying dpi. I saw that in other games people have pretty game's icon. What can I do about it?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the launcher icon in leaderboards is pulled down from Game Services API. Try to check these two settings:

1) icon you uploaded into graphic assets in Game Services Console.

2) branding information in Google Console - `code.google.com/apis/console` (APIs & auth -> Consent screen)